# How to add onclick event for each node of scatter chart of NVD3

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

How to add onclick event for each node of scatter chart of NVD3. [see the example](http://nvd3.org/examples/scatter.html)

Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a click event on nvd3.js graph](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598694/how-to-add-a-click-event-on-nvd3-js-graph)

Comment: Not a duplicate as the point onClick is much different than bars, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer Using D3 Dispatch Event

```
chart.scatter.dispatch.on("elementClick", function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

[Similar Question(Bar Chart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598694/how-to-add-a-click-event-on-nvd3-js-graph)

> API Documents Are Getting Better [NVD3 API](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/wiki/API-Documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a direct way to accomplish this using `NVD3`, but I had a similar issue before.

I used the `d3.selectAll()`, add this code once after the chart is loaded.

```
d3.selectAll("#chart svg path").on('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e); // Do your stuff here
});
```

Returns an object like the following when you click on a point

```
Object {data: Array[4], series: 3, point: 27}
```

Hope it helps