# nvd3: How highlight bar on click event?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

Like mousehover does, when the mouse goes hover the element (bar), it gets highlighted and drops that highlight when mouse leaves.

I'm wondering how to use that behavior but for a click event: highlight the bar when click.

Comment: Do exactly what you're doing on mouseover on click.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, mouseover event is native from nvd3, i'm not the author, that behavior is controlled from the lib itself.

Comment: I think that's done by assigning the class "hover" to the element, so all you'd need to do is assign that class on click.

Comment: Indeed, the class "hover" may solve this. But, how can I assign it to the element that was clicked?

Comment: You would need to select all elements that should have this behaviour and assign a click handler that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can always bind event listeners with d3. You select the element and you bind the event. In your concrete element, check the class of the bars and bind it.

Something like this:

```js
d3.selectAll(".nv-bar").on('click',
  function(){
    // add the effects or the class that enlarge the bar
});
```

reference: [How to add a click event on nvd3.js graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598694/how-to-add-a-click-event-on-nvd3-js-graph)