# Can we add click event in nvd3 forced directed graph node using angular

Tags: angular, click, nvd3.js

How can we add click event on each node in angular nvd3 forced directed graph?

Here is the link

http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/forceDirectedGraph

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a click event on nvd3.js graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598694/how-to-add-a-click-event-on-nvd3-js-graph)

Comment: No, it is not the duplicate question @Tamil. I asked for forced directed graph nvd3.

Comment: The events are same for all types of graphs in nvd3. So I marked it as a duplicate. Did you try the solution in the resolved question?

Comment: It  worked for multibar chart. Not for forced directed graph.