# How can I use D3.js "onClick" event with an nvd3 bar when zoomed in on chart data?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

Another obscure nvd3 question, this time with `onClick`.

I was able to use this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17598694/how-to-add-a-click-event-on-nvd3-js-graph/20567908) to figure out how to add an "onClick" event for bars using nvd3's [linePlusBarChart](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html).

The [jsfiddle here is working](https://jsfiddle.net/mzphq9wk/). Please feel free to click on a bar to see what I'm going for (using `alert` as a test). The relevant code is at the bottom of the JavaScript, also shown here:

```
d3.select('#chart1 svg')
    .datum(testdata)
    .transition().duration(500).call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });
    return chart;       
   }, function(){
      d3.selectAll(".nv-bar").on('click', 
          function(e){
            console.log(e);
            alert("You clicked on bar!");
          }
      );   
  });
```

**This is really great!** I am really happy with this as a solution. Using `function(e)` to get data from the NVD3 bar I can then use the bar data (quantity and date) to do other cool things with JavaScript.

**Unfortunately, I discovered that if I use the bottom panel to zoom in on a specific date range the 'onClick' event stops working.**

What is happening that causes the `onClick` event to become disassociated with a specific bar?

Is there an additional location that I need to add the `onClick` logic?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brush calls the `historicalBar` chart with the focus bars as selection.

After rendering the chart dispatches the `renderEnd` event.

We put the onclick callback in a separate function because we need it more then once

```
function addOnClick() {
  d3.selectAll(".nv-bar")
    .on('click', function(e) { console.log(e); alert("You clicked on bar!"); } );
}
```

We need to add a callback for this event

```
chart.bars.dispatch.on('renderEnd', addOnClick);
```

The complete code for the chart will be

```
var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
      .margin({top: 50, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 80})
      .legendRightAxisHint(' [Using Right Axis]')
      .color(d3.scale.category10().range());
    chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
    }).showMaxMin(false);
    chart.y2Axis.tickFormat(function(d) { return '$' + d3.format(',f')(d) });
    chart.bars.forceY([-3899468]).padData(false);
    chart.lines.forceY([-600]).padData(false);

    chart.x2Axis.tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
    }).showMaxMin(false);
    d3.select('#chart1 svg')
      .datum(testdata)
      .transition().duration(500).call(chart);
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });
    chart.bars.dispatch.on('renderEnd', addOnClick);
    return chart;
  }, addOnClick
);
function addOnClick() {
  d3.selectAll(".nv-bar")
    .on('click', function(e) { console.log(e); alert("You clicked on bar!"); } );
}
```

Comment: This works great. Do I need to add the function 'addOnClick()' before `nv.addGraph`?

Comment: @ScottSkiles No, in Javascript all has function/global scope, apart from `let`

Comment: Working fiddle if you want to add it: https://jsfiddle.net/mzphq9wk/28/